# Using XPath with XMLReader and xmlreader-iterators.php in a document with duplicate nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, iterator, xmlreader

I'm having trouble extracting certain parts of an XML file.

Take this example XML:

```
<toplevel>
 <profile>
  <technology type="java" />
  <technology type="dotnet" />
  <technology type="sdk" />
  <technology type="webserver" />
  <license interactive="false" />
  <groups></groups>
  <sensors></sensors>
  <measures>
   <measure id="example-name1" userdefined="true"></measure>
   <measure id="example-name2" userdefined="false"></measure>
  </measures>
  <transaction>
   <value>
    <measure id="example-name3" userdefined="true"></measure>
   </value>
  </transaction>
 </profile>
</toplevel>
```

I am using Iterators for PHP XMLReader (https://gist.github.com/hakre/5147685) to traverse this large document and read only nodes that are named 'measures'. Unfortunately there is a second section in the document that also contains 'measures'. On top of that, there are user defined and non user defined measures, I would like only the 'userdefined="true"' measures.

My code so far is:

```
require('xmlreader-iterators.php'); 
$xmlFile = "../xml/measures.xml";

$readerMeasures = new XMLReader();
$readerMeasures->open($xmlFile);
$dataMeasures = array();

$measures = new XMLElementIterator($readerMeasures, 'measure');
foreach ($measures as $measure) {
  $item = $measure->getAttribute('id');
  array_push($dataMeasures, $item);
}
```

Can someone please help me understand how to narrow down my results to just measures that are user defined from within the 'measures' section? Maybe this can be accomplished with XPath?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I've sorted out the user defined part:

```
foreach ($measures as $measure) {
  $userdefined = $measure->getAttribute('userdefined');
  $measure_name = $measure->getAttribute('id');
  if ($userdefined=="true") {
    echo "$measure_name<br>";
    $count++;
  }
}
```

But I have not been able to narrow down the Iterator to just pick up measures from within the "measures" section. It still looks in the "transactions" section as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need iterators here. You can achieve this with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

You would select elements as simple as this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$measures = $xml->xpath('//measures/measure[@userdefined="true"]');
```

Then you can loop over selected items:

```
foreach ($measures as $measure) {
    echo 'id: ', $measure['id'], PHP_EOL;
    echo 'value: ', $measure, PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61dfcd2965313c7cb562cdc558b6b1650ae0e71b).

Comment: Only problem here is performance. That is why people often use XMLReader to load each element and SimpleXML to operate on it. Because XMLReader can progress one element at a time. Whereas SimpleXML loads the entire file into memory.